# Алгоритм поиска ближайших точек (соседей)

Tags: алгоритм

Всем привет. У меня вдруг возник следующий вопрос по алгоритмам. Пусть на листе нанесено множество точек. Какие-то точки находятся рядом, а какие-то одинокие. Мне надо обвести те точки, которые находятся рядом. 
Например, я встал в точку А, и смотрю что в радиусе 1 см, у меня 5 точек. Обвожу это 5 точек. Затем смотрю есть ли у меня еще ближайшие точки уже с учетом 5 новых точек. Вижу, что есть и добавляю их в множество (обвожу их). Подобную рекурсию я делаю до тех пор, пока количество новых точек не начинает падать (резко падать). Если кол-во новых точек резко снижается, то я обвожу эти точки и принимаю решение, что все выбранные точки находятся рядом с точкой А. Метод позволяет мне находить на листе полигоны, с высокой концентрируются точки. 
Для решения мне приходит на ум метод "ближайших соседей" :-)

Подскажите, каким методом лучше решать эту задачу?

---

Друзья, всем спасибо за помощь. Я выбрал метод DBSCAN

Comment: эту задачу лучше решать методом  "ближайших соседей"

Comment: Учебник "Грокаем Алгоритмы". Адитья Бхаргава.

Comment: это называется кластеризация: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4_k-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%85

Answer (score 1, accepted):

метод DBSCAN лучше всего подошел я моей задачи